# Issue with changing an attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with changing the attribute for an id and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I guess it doesn't help that I'm new to this also.

I have a function that tests to make sure that I am pulling the correct id from the row in my form that I have dynamically created. It goes something like this:

```
myFunction() {
  var id = $(id).attr("id");
  alert("This is my id " + id);
}
```

This works with no problem and when I click the button assigned to alert me of my id it will give me the id of the dynamic row in my form. The issue is now when I try to change the id with this:

```
changeId() {
  var newId = $(id).attr("id", "x");
  alert("This is my new id " + newId);
}
```

What happens in this case is that it will alert saying "This is my new id [object Object]" instead of giving me the new id. Any suggestions? I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Those examples seem incomplete. They are missing the `function` keyword and the variable `id` is undefined. Also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.attr(attribute, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns the jQuery object again (so you can keep chaining), if you want that assigned ID, you need to do this:

```
changeId() {
  var newId = $(id).attr("id", "x").attr("id");
  alert("This is my new id " + newId);
}
```

Though the direct route is much better, for example:

```
changeId() {
  var newId = "x"
  $(id).attr("id", newId);
  alert("This is my new id " + newId);
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. Took the most effort to write and you even fetched the link and still managed to only be 3 seconds short of first :-)

Comment: Nick, why are you capturing `newId` in your revised `changeId()`? This would make a lot more sense to me: `changeId() { var newId = 'x'; $(id).attr('id', newId); alert('This is my new id ' + newId); }`

Comment: Thanks Nick and everyone who answered, it does exactly what I needed to do!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting, and not getting.The jQuery object is returned when you use `.attr` to set an attribute - not the value you have set it to. Try:

```
changeId() {
  $(id).attr("id", "x");
  var id = $(id).attr("id");
  alert("This is my new id " + newId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`attr(name, value)` returns a jQuery object. This is to support jQuery method chaining.

You want

```
changeId() {
  // ------------------------------v method chaining!
  var newId = $(id).attr("id", "x").attr("id");
  alert("This is my new id " + newId);
}
```

or simply

```
changeId() {
  $(id).attr("id", "x");
  alert("This is my new id " + id.id);
}
```

Maybe you also find a nicer name for the variable than `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Running `.attr()` with one argument returns the value of the attribute.

Running `.attr()` with two arguments returns the jQuery object against which it was called.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

`attr` when used to set an attribute returns the original jQuery object not the new attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `id` property of the DOM node. Works in all browsers and couldn't be simpler:

```
var el = document.getElementById("your_id");
el.id = "new_id";
alert(el.id);
```